# tikz node, auto-strut to drop descenders

Tags: tikz-pgf, strut

I am using a (huge) tikz picture to emulate a fillable form.  As a result, the text in the nodes has to line up.

To handle descenders, I have created a strut that "drops" the text back to the baseline in case of 'p','g','q' etc.  But it is annoying to have to do this by hand every single time.  Also, depending on \textls vs \textrm, characters have different descender characteristics (such as 'Q' and '/').

All user text is entered in a created command{}, so for instance
 `\newcommand{\ntstyle}{frequent singleton A or K}`.
Currently, all the commands are dropped into formatting blocks like
`\newcommand{\regtext}[1]{\scriptsize \usertext{\textls[-70]{#1}}}`

so we have nodes like 
`\node [right] at (x, y) {\regtext{ntstyle}}`.

I'm wondering if I can fix my formatting commands so that it can look at the input and determine if it needs the descender strut automatically, rather than forcing the user to remember every time.

Example:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz} %graphics tools. Also install ``ms'' package.
\RequirePackage{txfonts} %provides \varheartsuit and \vardiamondsuit
\RequirePackage{microtype} % allows us to stretch/shrink fonts to match
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % T1 font necessary to stretch and shrink
\RequirePackage{helvet} %provides Helvetica typeface
\RequirePackage{xifthen} %manipulate boolean values
\ProvidesPackage{template/mwe2022}

\newcommand{\tRegtext}[1]{\scriptsize \textsf{\textls[-70]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\usertext}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{serif}}{\textrm}{\textsf}}
\newcommand{\regtext}[1]{\scriptsize \usertext{\textls[-70]{#1}}}

\newboolean{serif}

%Two formatting commands, since TikZ places text blocks by their centers not
%their baselines: if you use p, y, or g, your text will look ``pushed upward'';
%if you use only lowercase letters, your text will look ``too high''.
\newcommand{\pfix}{\rule{0pt}{2.6mm}} %A way to re-center user text with p,y,g
\newcommand{\xfix}{\rule{0pt}{2.0mm}} %re-center text with no capital letters

% All coordinates of items inside here are given in millimeters
% from the bottom left corner of the card.
\newcommand{\drawconventioncard}{%
    \usetikzlibrary{scopes}%
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}%needed to position stuff in strings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.1,yscale=0.1,
    ];
    % draw a box around everything
    \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 215) -- (203, 215) -- (203, 0) -- cycle;

    \node [right] at (104, 200.7) {\tRegtext{Min Expected HCP when Balanced: Opening}};
    \node at (162, 201) {\regtext{\minHCPopen}};
    \node [right] at (168, 200.7) (mhbr) {\tRegtext{Responding}};
    \node at (191, 201) {\regtext{\minHCPresp}};

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%end of \drawconventioncard
```

and form:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% the card is 8'' wide, so the margins are very narrow to fit on letter size paper:
\usepackage{template/mwe}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=5mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\setboolean{serif}{true}
\newcommand{\minHCPopen}{peter\pfix{}}  % **I want this to not have to be manual**
\newcommand{\minHCPresp}{Paul}

\drawconventioncard
\end{document}
```

[image: with \pfix{} strut] :with pfix

[image: but with \pfix{} removed, it looks like] :no pfix

Comment: You can probably solve your problem using `\node[anchor=base west]` or `\node[anchor=mid west]` instead of `\node[right]` for the “peter” node. In the absence of a really minimal, abstracted example, I'm afraid I won't go any further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. By using relative location of the nodes, and setting the text height and text depth explicitly, you will have better alignment of the text in the nodes. I draw the frame for each node, to show the effect. You can comment that line to make it without frame.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %graphics tools. Also install ``ms'' package.
\usepackage{txfonts} %provides \varheartsuit and \vardiamondsuit
\usepackage{microtype} % allows us to stretch/shrink fonts to match
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T1 font necessary to stretch and shrink
\usepackage{helvet} %provides Helvetica typeface
\usepackage{xifthen} %manipulate boolean values
\newcommand{\tRegtext}[1]{\scriptsize \textsf{\textls[-70]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\usertext}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{serif}}{\textrm}{\textsf}}
\newcommand{\regtext}[1]{\scriptsize \usertext{\textls[-70]{#1}}}

\newboolean{serif}

%Two formatting commands, since TikZ places text blocks by their centers not
%their baselines: if you use p, y, or g, your text will look ``pushed upward'';
%if you use only lowercase letters, your text will look ``too high''.
\newcommand{\pfix}{\rule{0pt}{2.6mm}} %A way to re-center user text with p,y,g
\newcommand{\xfix}{\rule{0pt}{2.0mm}} %re-center text with no capital letters
% All coordinates of items inside here are given in millimeters
% from the bottom left corner of the card.
\newcommand{\drawconventioncard}{%
    \usetikzlibrary{scopes}%
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}%needed to position stuff in strings
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={
    draw, % comment this to node without frame
    minimum size=20pt,
    text depth=.1\baselineskip,
    text height=.5\baselineskip,
    },
    xscale=0.1,yscale=0.1,
    ];
    % draw a box around everything
    \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 215) -- (203, 215) -- (203, 0) -- cycle;

    \node (o) [right] at (104, 200.7) {\tRegtext{Min Expected HCP when Balanced: Opening}};
    \node [anchor=west,right=0.5em]  at (o.east) {\regtext{\minHCPopen}};
    \node [right] at (168, 200.7) (r) {\tRegtext{Responding}};
    \node [anchor=west,right=0.5em] at (r.east) {\regtext{\minHCPresp}};

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%end of \drawconventioncard
% the card is 8'' wide, so the margins are very narrow to fit on letter size paper:
%\usepackage{template/mwe}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=5mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\setboolean{serif}{true}
\newcommand{\minHCPopen}{peter}  % **I want this to not have to be manual**
\newcommand{\minHCPresp}{Paul}

\drawconventioncard
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try it (and read anchor) and see what it gets me.  And, it looks like, the tikzpicture parameters.

Comment: Looks like the text depth and text height keys are DTRT.  More experimentation, and then a global search and destroy, and it saves *everybody* a lot of work.  And, if I can use it for the header nodes as well, it will solve my "off grid" (the 200.7 instead of 201) issue as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Will attach more of the nodes as I have time; I disassociated them specifically because I had to "change the baseline" for template text that had to be dropped.  Now that it doesn't, I can reassociate them to get more consistent spacing - your "better alignment".  The TikZ manual is fabulous for its "programmed instruction" learning; but I wish it was easier to find all the 'options' in one place, for particular parameters.

Comment: @Mycroft You are welcome.